# How to create a dynamic array in a for loop in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I am working on a Python script in which I need to create an array of the following type. How can I make this type of array dynamically?

```
types = [
    Type('First'),
    Type('Second'),
    Type('Third', ['ThirdChild1', 'ThirdChild2']),
    Type('Fourth', ['FourthChild1', 'FourthChild2', 'FourthChild3'])
]
```

Here is the **test.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>First</name>
    </types>

    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Second</name>
    </types>

    <types>
        <members>ThirdChild1</members>
        <members>ThirdChild2</members>
        <name>Third</name>
    </types>

    <types>
        <members>FourthChild1</members>
        <members>FourthChild2</members>
        <members>FourthChild3</members>
        <name>Fourth</name>
    </types>

    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

and this is how get the names and elements from xml file

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

name = ET.Element("name")
members = ET.Element("members")

def retrieveType():
    for elem in root:
        for subelem in elem:
            if name.tag == str(subelem.tag).split('}')[1]:
                print('----------', subelem.text)
```

This subelem.text has the **members** and **name**, I want to put them in the array.

Comment: What's `ET`? Can you include the import?

Comment: thanks, i update the question.

Comment: Your XML Document is not in correct format can you please fix that?

Comment: @Jab thanks, actually closing tag was not indented properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using built-in types based on your approach is shown as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

name = ET.Element("name")
members = ET.Element("members")

def retrieveType():
    result = {}  # create an empty dictionary
    for elem in root:
        cur_members = []  # create an empty list
        cur_name = ""
        for subelem in elem:
            if name.tag == str(subelem.tag).split('}')[1]:
                cur_name = subelem.text
            if members.tag == str(subelem.tag).split('}')[1]:
                cur_members.append(subelem.text)  # add members to the list
        result[cur_name] = cur_members  # add the name/members to the dictionary
    return result


result = retrieveType()
```

You could adapt something like that to using an array of custom `Type` objects.
See [data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#) for more information.

Edit: Here is the final solution provided by [Anurag Shrivastava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577853/anurag-shrivastava):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

name = ET.Element("name")
members = ET.Element("members")

def retrieveType():
    finalResult = []
    for elem in root:
        cur_members = []
        cur_name = ""
        for subelem in elem:
            if name.tag == str(subelem.tag).split('}')[1]:
                cur_name = subelem.text
            if members.tag == str(subelem.tag).split('}')[1]:
                cur_members.append(subelem.text)
        finalResult.append('Type(' + str(cur_name) + ', ' + str(cur_members) + ')')
    return finalResult
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it saved my day. I add a line in your answer which gives me the exact solution.

Comment: You are welcome, I edited the answer to include your final solution, thanks for providing it!